# How can I remove a JScrollPane from a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

How can I remove a `JScrollPane` from a `JFrame`?

Here is an example of what I tried, but it isn't working:

```
Container gContentPane = frame.getContentPane();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(gContentPane);
frame.setContentPane( scroll );
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();

if (scroll != null){
    frame.getContentPane().remove(scroll);                      
    frame.revalidate(); 
    frame.repaint();
}
```

The `JScrollPane` is still there even after `frame.getContentPane().remove(scroll);`. What do I need to change to remove it?

Comment: You really should change frame.setContentPane(scroll) to `frame.getContentPane().add(scroll)`.  Currently, your code is trying to remove the JScrollPane from itself.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove something in Swing, firstly it has to be added. You did not add the scroll pane nowhere so I would suggest just changing the content pane to the previous one.

```
Container gContentPane = frame.getContentPane();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(gContentPane);
frame.setContentPane( scroll );
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();

if (scroll != null) {
    frame.setContentPane(gContentPane);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}
```